# Wireshark wont open pcap after modifying hex in vim

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I have a pcap file that can be opened in Wireshark. I opened the pcap file in Vim in hex mode with `:%!xxd` and modified a clear text letter e.g. `A` to `B`. However, after changing the file back to text mode with `:%!xxd -r` and trying to open the file in wireshark, I get either (depending on what I edit in the PCAP), errors:

1. The capture file appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet.
2. The file "capture.pcap" isn't a capture file in a format Wireshark understands.

If I go back into that same file in hex mode and undo the changes i.e. `B` back to `A`, I definitely will get error 2 mentioned above.

Any idea why just modifying the packet by one letter in hex mode will cause wireshark to behave this way? And why modifying back to the original state will definitely break the pcap file?

Comment: May be worth diffing the `xxd` output for both uneditted and editted files to see what exactly has been changed. My guess is that `vim` is doing something binary-unsafe in save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with either `vim` or the `xxd -r` command appending a line feed at the end. Just converting from hex then back again also triggers this.

Running the following:

```
xxd < 51996055.pcap > 51996055.pcap.before
vim -c ':%!xxd' -c '%!xxd -r' -c ':wq' 51996055.pcap
xxd < 51996055.pcap > 51996055.pcap.after
diff 51996055.pcap.before 51996055.pcap.after
```

gives the following output:

```
59c59
< 000003a0: 3031 3233 3435 3637                      01234567
---
> 000003a0: 3031 3233 3435 3637 0a                   01234567.
```

Opening this file in Wireshark gives me the first error that you encountered.

Running `:%!xxd` doesn't put `vim` into hex mode per se, it just replaces the the current buffer with the output of passing that through the command `xxd`. Likewise with the reverse.

There are [some ways](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_hex_editing) to improve `vim`'s hex editting abilities, or you could try another hex specific editor, like [`hexedit`](http://rigaux.org/hexedit.html).